# How to run swig on Cygwin with Python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, swig

I am trying to install and use swig in Cygwin, for creating a wrapper for a small Python (2.7) code. The instructions that I am following are from [swig tutorial page](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) and also [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?SwigFaqDLLUsingCygwin). These are the commands I ran (using the files shown in the link):

```
 swig -python example.i
 gcc -c example.c example_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7
 gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -o _example.so
```

I did not get any errors so far. Now when I run python I get this:

```
>>> import example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "example.py", line 21, in <module>
    _example = swig_import_helper()
  File "example.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_example')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _example
```

I checked the generated example.py file. The place the error is happening is like this:

[image: example.py]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: `import` is used for modules, so it is looking for a module called `example` which can not be found.

Comment: Not totally sure, but for cygwin python shouldn't the file extension still be .pyd, not .so?

Comment: Well, I followed the instructions given in the swig page. It says "import example" I thought swig will create a wrapper that creates the module example. I have attached above the code snippet in example.py where the error is happening, and there is no "module" in this file. Can someone tell me what code is expected to be generated by swig?